# Power Apps, TextSearchBox not searching for my String + integer field

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

I am trying to search my field "Title" which contains a combination of string + numbers.

I.e.  "Stack-1234" is a record in my field "Title".

Items in BrowseGallery1:

```
If(Toggle2.Value=false, SortByColumns(Filter([@'Documentation Tracker'],Lower(Requestor_two) = Lower(User().Email) Or Lower(Approver.Value) = Lower(User().Email) && StartsWith(Title, TextSearchBox1.Text)), "Title", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending)), SortByColumns(Filter([@'Documentation Tracker'], StartsWith(Title, TextSearchBox1.Text)), "Title", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending)))
```

However I see more then what I am searching, see below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this formula in `items` property of your gallery control:

```
If(
    Toggle2.Value = false,
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            Or(Lower(Requestor_two) = Lower(User().Email), Lower(Approver.Value) = Lower(User().Email)) && StartsWith(Title, TextSearchBox1.Text)
        ),
        "Title",
        If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending)
    ),
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            StartsWith(Title, TextSearchBox1.Text)
        ),
        "Title",
        If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending)
    )
)
```

**Documentation**: [And, Or, and Not functions in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-logicals)

**Note**: Sometimes filtering may happen when you click outside the text input control

Comment: Thanks !! One question, is there anyway to search for a portion of the "title" Ie. instead of searching CAATTS-2022-1234, is there a way to search 1234?

Comment: Instead of `StartsWith(Title, TextSearchBox1.Text)`, use `TextSearchBox1.Text in Title`.